# Display user information with Firebase and Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I have built a simple app with Nextjs and Firebase (right now, I'm only using the authentication providing by Firebase). I made a login component and a greetingUser component whose roles are defined as follow :

- greetingUser : display the name of the user currently logged in and a greeting message;

```
// greetingUse.js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from './User/User';

export default function GreetUser(){
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>hello, {user.user.name} !</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

- login : there are two buttons (login and logout). When the user log in, I want to receive the name of the user (user.displayName) and update the greetingUser component to display that name.

```
// login.js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import React, { useContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from './User/User';
import { auth } from '../utils/firebase';

export default function Login() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  const state = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log(state);
  console.log(state.user);
  const updateUserDetails = () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        return user.displayName;
      } else {
        return "You are logged out";
      }
    })
    console.log(state.user);
  }



  return (
    <>
      <div className="btn-group">
        <button 
        id="logInBtn" 
        className="btn btn-primary"
        onClick={() => auth.signInWithPopup(provider) && state.setUser(updateUserDetails())}>
          Login
      </button>
        <button 
        id="logOutBtn" 
        className="btn btn-danger"
        onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>
          Logout
        </button>
      </div>
      <p>hello {state.user.name}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

You'll notice that I'm using react context. After some research, that the solution I found. Here is the Provider code :

```
// User.js
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext({
  user: {name: "User"},
  setUser: () => {}
});

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
  const setUser = (user) => {
    setState({...state, user: user})
  }

  const initState = {
    user: {name: "User"},
    setUser: setUser
  }

  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={state}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
};

export { UserContext, UserContextProvider };
```

The problem is when logging in, the value of the user object is undefined resulting in an error that prevent the page from rendering :

> login.js?4f9b:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Login (login.js?4f9b:42)

I thing it's because while authenticating, the value of user is unknow, but after the authentification is completed, the value of user is not updated.
I did some research, but I don't find a solution adapted to my problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am trying to get the currently logged in user's information by calling `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` but the `currentUser` is null.